# Using std::search to find multiple occurrence of pattern

Tags: c++, search

I want to use function search or other similar function to find multiple occurrence of given pattern.

This is my code:

```
#include <cstring>  
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>  
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <map>   
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  std::vector<int> haystack;

  string a = "abcabcabc";
  string b = "abc";
  string::iterator it;
  it = search(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end());

  if(it!=a.end()){
      cout << it-a.begin()<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This code return 0 as the first occurrence of pattern "abc" , would like to return 0, 3, 6. That would be all of the indexes in the original string where pattern begins.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all a substring's occurrences and locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034750/find-all-a-substrings-occurrences-and-locations)

Comment: You need a loop, which should finish when `it == a.end()`. What did you try? And is there any particular reason you aren't using `a.find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(size_t pos=a.find(b,0); pos!=std::string::npos; pos=a.find(b,pos+1)) {
    std::cout << pos << std::endl;
}
```

This uses `std::basic_string::find` ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic%5fstring/find)) directly to find the starting position of the substring.

Comment: Does this code search a from begining to end everytime ? Or it continues from last position ?

Comment: It continues from `pos+1`.

Comment: What if a case-insensitive search is to be done? In that case, find() will not work. And I am not sure how to advance iterator in search(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `search` function searches the first string `a` for any occurence of the elements of the second string `b`. As Your second string contains the elements `a`, `b` and `c` the code would return an iterator to the first position, then to the second, the third one,...

What You what to use is the `find` function. It returns an iterator to the element that equals the one that You were searching for. In Your case You're search the string `a` for the element `abc`. So You would have to call

```
string::iterator it = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), "abc");
while (it != a.end()) {
    // Do whatever you want to do...
    ++it;
    it = std::find(it, a.end(), "abc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//find first result index
auto find_index = str.find("st");
while(string::npos != find_index) {
  cout << "found at: " << find_index << endl;
  //find next
  find_index = str.find("st",find_index+1);
}
```