# Find all instances of string in anotherstring

Tags: c++, string, loops, find

Below i have a peice of code that compares two strings.

```
if (long.find(short) != string::npos) {
        cout << "FOUND";
}
```

This only tells me if it finds the short string in the long string. But how can i go about finding all the instances and tell the user where those instances of the string show?

I get the idea to maybe make this a loop but im having trouble implementing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all a substring's occurrences and locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034750/find-all-a-substrings-occurrences-and-locations)

Comment: I am looking into c++

Comment: the related dup is c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "we are searching for searching here";
    std::string str = "searching";
    std::string::size_type start = test.find(str); // find the first instance
    while(start != std::string::npos) // repeat for the rest
    {
        std::cout << "Found on pos: " << start << std::endl;
        start = test.find(str, start + 1);
    }
}
```

Side note: don't use `long` and `short` as your string names, as they are C++ reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

One of the overloads of [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) allows you to tell it where to start looking. So after finding one occurrence, call `find()` again with the previous location plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for a sample implementation:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() 
{
   std::string long_str ("abcabcabcabc");
   std::string short_str("abc"); 
   while( true)
   {
      std::size_t found = long_str.find(short_str);
      if (found == std::string::npos)
        break;
      long_str = long_str.substr(found+short_str.length());
      std::cout<<long_str<<"\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

abcabcabc

abcabc

abc