# How do I get a particular instance of a string that repeats multiple times in a string

Tags: c++

I want to convert the data in the string `KeyData` (which is present is `<eg2keydata>` attribute) to `*`. But it always takes the first instance of `keyData` in the string `msg`. How can I get the particular instance everytime I want to convert? I am new to this and I am unable to debug it.I am not sure about about the for loop. Anyone please help me find the mistake.Thanks!!

```
  const std::string& msg = "<PolicyAction><ManualKeyPolicyAction><TransformData SPI=\"1219546177\"><eg1KeyData Protocol=\"abc\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"d789c\"></eg1KeyData><eg2KeyData Protocol=\"hm\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"4328a036abfcf5e9\"></eg2KeyData><Tunne<PolicyAction><ManualKeyPolicyAction><TransformData SPI=\"1219546177\"><eg1KeyData Protocol=\"aes-cbc\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"d789c\"></eg1KeyData><eg2KeyData Protocol=\"hmac-sha1-96\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"4328a03\"></eg2KeyData><SaltData ";
  std::size_t search1 = msg.find("<eg2KeyData");
  const std::string from1 = "KeyData=\"";
  const std::string to1 = "\"></eg2KeyData>";
  std::size_t endpos1 = msg.find(to1);
  std::string s = msg;
  std::size_t l1 = 0;
  if (msg.find("<eg2KeyData") != std::string::npos)
  {
      l1 = msg.find("KeyData=\"",search1);

    if (l1 != 0)
    {
      std::size_t r1 = endpos1 - l1 - from1.length();
      s.replace(l1 + from1.length(), r1, r1, '*');
    }
  }
  std::cout << s;
```

Comment: If you want to parse XML data, why not use an XML parser? There's no shortage of ones to choose from.

Comment: But my task is to do it in c++. I want to know how to find all the occurances of a substring using the find command,not just the first occurance.

Comment: I'll point out that pure C++ XML parsers do exist (google's first hit, [tinyxml](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/master/tinyxml2.cpp)), and parsing XML data yourself, the hard way is a terrible, terrible idea. Feel free to pass it on to the person setting you the task, who should know better.

Comment: What you're trying to do needs some serious parsing. If you still want to use an ad-hoc solution, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034750/find-all-a-substrings-occurrences-and-locations).

Comment: Your XML data is still malformed. There's stuff like `<Tunne<` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most important note first: not using an XML library to do this for you is madness. Trying to do this properly for complex data without using something that understands the XML format is a very, very bad idea.

---

If you want to find the next instance of a substring you've just found, you just need to tell `find` where you want to start searching from, eg.

```
const std::string& msg = "<PolicyAction><ManualKeyPolicyAction><TransformData SPI=\"1219546177\"><eg1KeyData Protocol=\"abc\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"d789c\"></eg1KeyData><eg2KeyData Protocol=\"hm\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"4328a036abfcf5e9\"></eg2KeyData><Tunne<PolicyAction><ManualKeyPolicyAction><TransformData SPI=\"1219546177\"><eg1KeyData Protocol=\"aes-cbc\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"d789c\"></eg1KeyData><eg2KeyData Protocol=\"hmac-sha1-96\" KeyLength=\"64\" KeyData=\"4328a03\"></eg2KeyData><SaltData ";

size_t p = msg.find("KeyData=");

while (p != std::string::npos)
{
  std::cout << p << " ";
  p = msg.find("KeyData=", p + 1);
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

which then gives the result

```
111 181 342 422
```

You can then search for the next two instances of the string `\"`, and use those positions to calculate the beginning and end points of the text you want to alter.

Just read the docs!
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Alternatively, you might consider using a regular expression:

```
std::regex r("KeyData=\\\"([a-z0-9]+)\\\"");

for (auto i = std::sregex_iterator(msg.begin(), msg.end(), r); i != std::sregex_iterator(); i++)
  std::cout << i->position() << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;
```

This gives the same result. I'm not going to go into the details of how to use regular expressions here though.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: This works if there is only one occurance of <eg2KeyData>. what if i have multiple occurances of <eg2KeyData>

Comment: @leenvr unless you can give actual examples of source data, and actual examples of what you want to find, we will just have to guess what you want. I have answered your question as it currently stands. If this isn't the answer you wanted, you will have to edit your question so that it _actually asks what you want_.

Comment: sorry for not giving the correct source string. I have edited my code. In the updated code,Can you please help me convert the KeyData in eg2KeyData at both the places in the string

Comment: @leenvr I've made a very small edit to my code to use a while loop. The same fundamental technique is being used. All positions of `KeyData` are returned. Is this what you wanted?